# How to stop one javascript function if another Javascript function is active

Tags: javascript

I currently have a js function for a sticky nav on scroll up and a js click function for a hamburger to full screen menu transition. Currently, when my full screen menu is open I am still able to scroll down, it then disappears using the sticky nav function. I would like the sticky nav function to be disabled when the full screen menu is open.

How can I avoid this? Thank you!

Please see my code below and in an attached screenshot:

**Sticky Nav JS:**

```
const body = document.body;
let lastScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

    if ($('.menu-overlay').hasClass('active')) {
        return;
    }

    if (currentScroll <= 0) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    }

    if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
        body.classList.add("scroll-down");
    }
    if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
        body.classList.add("scroll-up");
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

**Hamburger to full screen menu JS:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.hamburger-menu').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
            $('.menu .menu-list').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
            $('.menu .menu-list').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
        }
    })
})();
```

I tried to avoid this with a return if condition in the sticky nav function but this didn't work:

```
if ($('.menu-overlay').hasClass('active')) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you add a minimal html of how you expect that js code to interact with the page? the question is hard to understand because you check if the `.menu-overlay` has the `active` class but you don't add that class to the element anywhere

Comment: Isn't it ´$('.hamburger-menu')´ instead of ´$(.hamburger-overlay)´ that has possibly the active class?

Comment: Try this `if ($('.hamburger-menu').hasClass('active')) { return; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see when `$('.menu-overlay').hasClass('active')` would have the class of `active`, so the following would never trigger or be true:

```js
if ($('.menu-overlay').hasClass('active')) {
    return;
}
```

You probably want:

```js
if ($('.hamburger-menu').hasClass('active')) {
    return;
}
```